# how to create public profiles for registered users in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, passport.js

i tried something like this:

```
app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  res.render("profile.ejs", { id: req.user.id });
});

app.get("/u/:id", (req, res) => {
  var user = {
    id: Date.now().toString(),
    email: req.body.email,
  };

  db.each(`SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?;`, function (err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
      return res.redirect("/");
    }
    res.render("profile", { id: foundUser });
  });
});
```

but it doesn't work. i cannot go to localhost:3000/u/:id and see its profile.(which should just show me its id)
how to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have defined the necessary dependencies and set up the Express.js server correctly.
2. Ensure that you have established a connection to your database (db) before executing queries.
3. In the `/u/:id` route, you're defining a new user object with an id and email property. However, it seems like you want to fetch the user's data from the database based on the provided id parameter. Therefore, you should remove the user object creation and modify the code to query the database using the id parameter.

Please check this my guessing code:

```js
app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  res.render("profile.ejs", { id: req.user.id });
});

app.get("/u/:id", (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;

  db.get(`SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?;`, userId, function (err, foundUser) {
    if (err || !foundUser) {
      req.flash("error", "User not found.");
      return res.redirect("/");
    }
    res.render("profile", { id: foundUser.id });
  });
});
```

Good Success.

Comment: its not working. as i cannot go to localhost:3000/u/1 and see its profile.

Comment: First, Verify that the route is set up correctly.
app.get("/u/:id", (req, res) => {
   console.log("This is test console");
   console.log("Email, ID:", req.body.email, req.body.id);
})

2.Check if the database query is executing correctly:
Verify that you have a users table in your database and that it contains the necessary data.
Ensure that the query SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ? is correct and returns the expected results.
Make sure your database connection is established and working correctly.